# AppCode 3.2 doesn't see .xcasset nested folders

Tags: xcode, appcode, xcasset

I've just started using AppCode and noticed that it doesn't see images in nested  folders inside `.xcasset`. Is there any way to fix it?

In example below there is no image `ImageInSomeFolder` (and `SomeFolder`) in AppCode. Neither `ImageInSomeFolder` is available as autocomplete in code editor. `ResourceNotFoundInspection` warning appears:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well...

See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/OC-8650#u=1401303800200&tab=Linked%20Issues

and https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/OC-11173#tab=Linked%20Issues&u=1417067507115

For relevant bugs logged with JetBrains… in 2014.